# How to find when live RTMP stream stops in ActionScript?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, rtmp

I've currently got the following code, where `streamVideo` is an FLVPlayBack component:

```
streamVideo.addEventListener( VideoEvent.STATE_CHANGE, onVideoStateChange );

streamVideo.isLive = true;
streamVideo.source = "rtmp://mystreamurl";

function onVideoStateChange(evt:VideoEvent):void {
  var streamVideo:FLVPlayback = evt.target as FLVPlayback;
  switch (evt.state) {
    case VideoState.CONNECTION_ERROR:
      trace( 'Connection error' );
      break;
    default:
    trace( 'Player is: ' + evt.state );
  }
}
```

This gives me `Player is: playing` when my stream comes on, but when my stream goes off, I don't get any sort of notification.

Answer (score 0):

I remember playing with a similar issue when playing with Adobe Cirrus and netstreams. I'm not sure if this will work, but try checking to see if the videoDataRate == 0 under your streamVideo's [metaData](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/fl/video/FLVPlayback.html#metadata) property.

Comment: no, that doesn't seem to work for me. I'm using `trace` to output it out, and even after the stream stops and the video doesn't continue in the FLVPlayback, it's still giving me 1800.

Comment: If you can't find another way...I'd just do it with a netstream and a video object. I know in the netstream class you can access bytesAvailable. When that's 0, the stream is over (or in my case the user stopped talking). 

Their might me another way though, but if you're running out of time, there's a workaround for ya.

Comment: hmm, ok - how would I get bytesAvailable set up? I have a `NetStream` object.

Comment: I'm also trying to detect when the stream would start - how is that possible using `NetConnection` and `NetStream`?